# Getting the target of each anchor link for animating scroll (jQuery scrolltop)

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, anchor, href, scrolltop

Can anyone tell me how to edit this code so that it applies to all anchor links with the class "enablescroll", then scroll to their respective target id's?

Right now I have:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.enablescroll').click(function(){  //when links with class "enablescroll" clicked
        $('.pagecontainer').animate({  //animate this container not the viewport
            scrollTop: $("#target").offset().top  //scroll to the div with id "target"
        }, 1000);
    });
});
</script>
```

This obviously only works if I have 1 scroll destination named "target". But I have like 50 links, each one with a different target id, like this:

```
<div class="pagecontainer">

<a href="#section1" class="enablescroll">Section 1</a>
<a href="#section2" class="enablescroll">Section 2</a>
<a href="#section3" class="enablescroll">Section 3</a>
<a href="#section4" class="enablescroll">Section 4</a>
<a href="#section5" class="enablescroll">Section 5</a>

....

<div id="section1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris eros ipsum, ullamcorper in tincidunt ut, fringilla vel risus. Cras purus arcu, vulputate eu tempus sit amet, gravida et diam. Nulla commodo aliquam metus.</div>

<div id="section2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris eros ipsum, ullamcorper in tincidunt ut, fringilla vel risus. Cras purus arcu, vulputate eu tempus sit amet, gravida et diam. Nulla commodo aliquam metus.</div>

<div id="section3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris eros ipsum, ullamcorper in tincidunt ut, fringilla vel risus. Cras purus arcu, vulputate eu tempus sit amet, gravida et diam. Nulla commodo aliquam metus.</div>

<div id="section4">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris eros ipsum, ullamcorper in tincidunt ut, fringilla vel risus. Cras purus arcu, vulputate eu tempus sit amet, gravida et diam. Nulla commodo aliquam metus.</div>

<div id="section5">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris eros ipsum, ullamcorper in tincidunt ut, fringilla vel risus. Cras purus arcu, vulputate eu tempus sit amet, gravida et diam. Nulla commodo aliquam metus.</div>

</div>
```

How do I get the target for each link then assign them to that scroll script? I remember the syntax was something like:

```
$(this.getAttribute("href"))
```

But I don't know how the rest of the syntax.

Thanks.

Comment: `$(this).attr('href')`

Comment: Doesn't seem to work... `$('.enablescroll').click(function(){  
        $('.pagecontainer').animate({
            scrollTop: $(this).attr('href').offset().top
        }, 1000);
    });`

Comment: I suggest reading up on `scope`. Your `this` is nested too deep, thus it is referring to the element with the `pagecontainer` class. Declare it as a variable as the first statement in your click function handler.

Comment: I declared it as a variable for the click function, but it's still not working. Can you check if the syntax is still wrong? I believe now the logic is right? `$('.enablescroll').click(function(){ 
    var targetlink = $(this).attr('href');
    $('.pagecontainer').animate({  
     scrollTop: targetlink.attr('href').offset().top  
    }, 1000);
   });`